# What structure is traversed to deallocate pages, when a process terminates? (Page Table or something else?)

Tags: linux, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I am trying to understand the nature of the operations carried out regarding the deallocation of physical memory when a process terminates.

Assumed that page table for the process is a multi-level tree structure thats implemented on Linux.

My current understanding is that the OS would need to deallocate each physical page frame that is mapped to whatever subset of the virtual addresses for which the Page Table entry (PTE) exists. This could happen by a traversal of the multi-level tree PT structure & for the PTEs that have their valid bit set, the physical frame descriptor corresponding to the PTE is added to the free list (which is used in the Buddy allocation process).

My question is: Is the traversal of the Page Table actually done for this? An alternative, faster way would be to maintain a linked list of the page frame descriptors allotted to a process, for each process & then traverse that linearly during process termination. Is this more generic & faster method instead followed?

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question, because you don't define what Page Table is to you.

Comment: Why do you ask? Is it from a kernel hacker point of view ?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it. It looks very unclear (and may give the impression that you are confusing virtual memory & physical pages)

Comment: copy-on-write (CoW) means that any given phys page might still be referenced by another process, or be part of the pagecache (e.g. for file-backed mmap).  So no, traversing the hardware page-tables are definitely not what happens.  (Except maybe for reclaiming the space used to hold the page directories / page tables themselves.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that page gets *physically* deallocated at process ending.

My understanding is that [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) is managed by the kernel.

But each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), which the kernel changes:

- for explicit syscalls changing it, ie. [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)
- at program start thru [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (which can be thought of several virtual `mmap`-s as described by the segments of the [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) program [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) file)
- at process termination, as if each segment of the address space was virtually `munmap`-ed

And when a process terminates, it is its virtual address space (but not any *physical RAM pages*) which gets destroyed or deallocated!

So the [page table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) (whatever definition you give to it) is probably managed inside the kernel by a few primitives like adding a segment to virtual address space and removing a segment from it. The virtual space is *lazily* managed, since the kernel uses [copy on write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) techniques to make `fork` fast.

Don't forget that some pages (e.g. the code segment of shared libraries) are *shared* between processes and that every task of a multi-threaded process are sharing the same virtual address space.

BTW, the [Linux kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) is [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you should study its source code (from http://kernel.org/). Look also on http://kernelnewbies.org ; memory management happens inside the [mm/](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm) subtree of the kernel source.

There are lots of resources. Look into [linux-kernel-slides](http://free-electrons.com/doc/training/linux-kernel/linux-kernel-slides.pdf), slides#245 for a start, and there are many books and resources about the Linux kernel... Look for [vm_area_struct](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=vm_area_struct), `pgetable`, etc...

Comment: Please edit your question. Your comment is even more confusing. Did you read some documentation about MMUs? Perhaps study [MMIX](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/mmix.html) and/or [Risc-V](http://riscv.org/) before x86...

Comment: My question is more about the functioning of the MMU on the orders of the kernel. Perhaps I did not manage to convey this in my question.

In your answer, you mention details of the mapping & unmapping of the executable image to the virtual address space.

Comment: I am interested in the mapping of the virtual pages to physical page frames. As I understand it, it is created by lazy paging, when a page fault occurs & an entry is created correspondingly in the Page Table. When the process terminates, this mapping has to be deleted in the Kernel (which is achieved by just invalidating the entire page table for the process. But before, the physical page frames need to be freed and added to the free lists right? I want to understand more about that process of freeing the page frames - when does it occur, how it occurs. Can you help with that ?

Comment: Again, avoid commenting but edit your question to improve it. Your question needs a lot of improvement.